# Here API customization tools

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Here Android SDK and trying to customize my map. I follow the example at [enter link description here](https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/MapCustomizationExample.zip). But for some `CustomizableVariables` I can't assign color because I don't understand what exactly such parameter means. For example at mapbox has [mapbox studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) - it really simplifies the process of custom scheme creation. Is there anything like that for here maps? 
It would be very useful at least be able to find specific areas on the real map, to decide what color or size to assign.

Maybe there is some way I can move the map to the area with specific `CustomizableVariables`? Or is there any docs, explaining what all such parameters means?

Comment: You know we can't download files from 'unknown' sources. Can you add the relevant code in your question please?

Comment: Its the link from here guys, which they provide as an example of customization process. https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics/map-customization.html  here you can find the official docs about customization. My question is concrete and targeted to here maps developers firstly. (or people who done this before).

Comment: It is not supported and the current CustomizableVariables do not work for all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no high level user interface to mange map customization for Here Android SDK. The customization is based on using the available CustomizableVariables. For many of them, the naming is self explanatory. Otherwise it is a hit and trial approach to see how the variables affect the visuals of the map.